# Discover Plugin-JARS in Classpath in Spring

Tags: java, spring, classpath

Is there a way in Spring to discover a 
"plugin"-JAR from the classpath,
and load its applicationContext.xml dynamicaly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved a plugin-like system with Spring by following this approach:

- Each plug-in must contain a spring-context file with a specific name and package prefix (for example, *com.example.myApp.whatever* containing *plugin.xml*, or applicationContext.xml if you prefer).
- For the plug-in to be detected in the classpath, the host application should dynamically import all the context files contributed by any jar following the previos scheme. This is achieved with a wildcard-based import in spring config:

  ```
   <import resource="classpath*:/com/example/myApp/**/plugin.xml" />
  ```
- Provided that each plug-in defines beans of a known interface (e.g., MyInterface). The host application can define a property of type List <MyInterface> and define the bean as autowire="byType" in order to retrieve all the beans of the MyInterfaceType in a list.